# So, running Drush update messed up your SVN repo

Tags: drush

I'm working on a client's site. We had the `sites` folder as the root of a SVN repository. At some point we ran drush to do module/core updates but Drush was (mistakenly) set to ignore the repository.

Now we have a lot of folders (mostly modules) that have the tilde SVN status. For example, here's five actual folders:

```
~       all/modules/webform
~       all/modules/password_policy
~       all/modules/views
~       all/modules/services
~       all/modules/pathauto
```

We've spent time reading about [how one addresses the tilde status in a general sense. There's a Stack Overflow question on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853405/what-does-the-subversion-status-symbol-mean). It's pretty clear that Drush deleted these folders that had `.svn` folders in them and replaced them with new ones. These new untracked folders have the same name, so the parent folder's `.svn` index is confused. In essence, we can't run update because there's something already there taking up the name we need.

What's the best practice?

1. Delete the untracked folders, run `svn update`, try to use Drush to update again with proper configuration. *Edit: Since there are hundreds of nested folders, a bash script would be nice.*
2. Somehow force a commit of these new files? If that's possible, how to do it? (Note: in this sort of overwhelming situation we would be okay with the revisions on those modules breaking as long as we can commit again)
3. Other?

*Note: This is more of an SVN question than a Drupal question, but it's a direct effect of Drush. I assumed Drush-savvy users have bumped into this sort of thing before. Also, I want to know how I can solve the issues without making my client's site crumble.*

Comment: When running in to the same issue I find it easiest to do option 1.

Comment: I think this is a good question for DA.

Comment: @Bart even if there are hundreds of nested folders? I would honestly prefer option 2, but I can't find a way to do it. Maybe a script would help..

Comment: I just do `rm -R folder` and then `svn update`, svn sorts out the rest (restores everything from svn, including subfolders).

Comment: That's too destructive. I need the equivalent of a merge, not a revert. (Sad: The client has already had a chance to make more changes past the update. More sad: they don't care about the fact that we're trying to use version control. I asked about installing Git and got shot down.)

Comment: How "drush was (mistakenly) set to ignore the repository"? Did you force --version-control=backup? if so, the .svn folders are in some place at ~/drush-backups and you could bring them back with rsync